# asp mvc 2 unit test debug

Tags: .net, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-2

my code

```
[TestMethod()]
    public void SelectTest()
    {
        DateTime begin = new DateTime(); // TODO: инициализация подходящего значения
        DateTime end = new DateTime(); // TODO: инициализация подходящего значения
        int agrNum = 0; // TODO: инициализация подходящего значения
        Core.Core.Select(begin, end, agrNum);
        Assert.Inconclusive("Невозможно проверить метод, не возвращающий значение.");
    }
```

i'm pressing "debug test" button.
when Core.Core.Select gets exception, execution of test fails, and intest results i'm getting information about exception. how can i force him to break on exception, and show me information??? 
vs2010 ultimate, win xp sp3 32bit

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

1. In Visual Studio main menu, click on ***Debug -> Exceptions...***
2. Enable breaking on all thrown CLR exceptions (or refine that rule by selecting specific exception types), like shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Put try {} catch {} clouse around Core.Core.Select statement:

```
[TestMethod()]
    public void SelectTest()
    {
        DateTime begin = new DateTime(); // TODO: инициализация подходящего значения
        DateTime end = new DateTime(); // TODO: инициализация подходящего значения
        int agrNum = 0; // TODO: инициализация подходящего значения
        try{
            Core.Core.Select(begin, end, agrNum);
        }
        catch(Exception){}
        Assert.Inconclusive("Невозможно проверить метод, не возвращающий значение.");
    }
```

Comment: are u kiddin' me? why would i do it? thats not the way

Comment: i want to watch at exception, and watch its information, not to avoid it

Comment: The unit test interface supplies you with exception details and relevant information why test failed. Didn't understand what you exactly need.

Comment: to enter method, watch the line where exception throwed, press right button, get details, like innerException and etc. just like in debugging of winforms project for example?

Comment: Test result will display full stack trace. But if you want to step into Core.Core.Select (I'm assuming it's in another dll) you'll need pdb file for it.